# Finding elevation of polygon

Tags: dem, elevation

I am trying to find the elevation of a flood polygon. Is it possible to do either using ArcGIS or QGIS or in Python?

I understand that for the point feature, we can find it but what about multiple polygons.

Comment: Zonal Statistics (mean, min and/or max). Available in ArcGIS, QGIS and [python](https://pythonhosted.org/rasterstats)

Comment: Ok so if i multiply the mean value with the pixel size, I would be able to get flood volume?

Comment: Not really, well very roughly perhaps.  If you want volume, use proper 3D analyses.

Comment: Please decide whether it is ArcGIS Pro, ArcMap, QGIS or Python that you wish to ask about in this particular question. I suggest QGIS to match the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to do afterwards.

Zonal statitistics:

> This algorithm calculates statistics of a raster layer for each
> feature of an overlapping polygon vector layer.

[image]

Or Drape:

> This algorithm sets the z value of every vertex in the feature
> geometry to a value sampled from a band within a raster layer.